# Firestore iOS OR query (whereField("X", in: ["Y", "Z"])

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to the firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) (make sure to select Swift for the code examples), Firestore iOS SDK allows OR queries. There is no OR operator, but the query syntax

`ref.whereField("X", in: ["Y", "Z"])`

should fulfil the same purpose. 
However, although I'm using the latest version of Firestore for iOS (1.2.1) and FirebaseCore (5.4.1) this syntax does not seem to be supported.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `whereField(_:in:)` query operator was introduced in version 6.12 of the Firebase iOS SDK. For this type of information, always check the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6120_-_november_5_2019).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Apparently, limiting Auth to a version below 6.0 and Storage below 4.0 prevented Firebase Core from updating to the latest version, although I had not set any version limit for Firebase Core.